# how to crop bitmap of wallpaper

Tags: android, bitmap, android-bitmap

I have a bitmap of my current wallpaper. I need to crop it to set behind a layout. main problem that I am facing is that cropping of that bitmap.
Here is my code.

```
      Bitmap icon = utiles.drawableToBitmap(wallpaperDrawable);
    blurredBitmap = BlurBuilder.blur(this, icon);

     public void drawBlurImage() {

    if (resizedBitmap == null &&getHeight()!=0 ) {

       resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(CategoriesActivity.blurredBitmap, dpToPx(80), dpToPx(64), getWidth()-dpToPx(165), getHeight()-dpToPx(30));
        resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(resizedBitmap, this.getWidth(), this.getHeight(), true);
        invalidate();
    }
    // Drawable drawable = new BitmapDrawable(getContext().getResources(), resizedBitmap);

}
```

here is what I have got so far.You can see in the picture blur bitmap is not set correctly behind two apps. below is code that is for cropping a bitmap, I have set fix value for another wallpaper that was showing good but its not good for every wallpaper.

```
resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(CategoriesActivity.blurredBitmap, dpToPx(80), dpToPx(64), getWidth()-dpToPx(165), getHeight()-dpToPx(30));
```

suggestions will be appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use a custom library like [Android Image Cropper](https://github.com/ArthurHub/Android-Image-Cropper) to crop the image with ease. To crop an image launch the `CropImageActivity` and pass the `uri` of the image, this way:

```
   CropImage.activity(imageUri)
  .setGuidelines(CropImageView.Guidelines.ON)
  .start(this);
```

And override the `onActivityResult()` method to retrieve the cropped image back:

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
   if (requestCode == CropImage.CROP_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE) {
       CropImage.ActivityResult result = CropImage.getActivityResult(data);
       if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
           Uri resultUri = result.getUri();
       } else if (resultCode == CropImage.CROP_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_RESULT_ERROR_CODE) {
           Exception error = result.getError();
       }
   }
}
```

Its that simple.

Comment: But, what If I want to pass bitmap?.